# Can't pass parameter to a method when wildcard is in the form <? extends capture of ? extends Identity>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have an  interface that'ss defined as follows:

```
public interface MyApi<T extends Identity>
```

And a method read:

```
List<ReadApiResponse<? extends T>> read(ReadApiRequest request);
```

In my calling class I have a private method that should operate on the `read` result and its signature is:

```
public MyClass<T extends Identity> {

    private List<T> sortResults(List<ReadApiResponse<? extends Identity>> response) {
         // Do something here
      }

}
```

I try to call the private method:

```
var results = read(request);
List<T> sortedResults = sortResults(results);
```

But I get the message:

```
'sortResults(java.util.List<com.mypackage.ReadApiResponse<? extends com.mypackage.Identity>>)' in '...' cannot be applied to '(java.util.List<com.mypackage.model.ReadApiResponse<? extends capture<? extends com.mypackage.Identity>>>)'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried to cast it with Intellij's problem-solver suggestions and it also throws an error

Comment: Does `Identifiable` extend or implement `Identity`?

Comment: @E-Riz - Sorry, no `Identifiable` it's all `Identity`. Fixed the question

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the bounded wilcard form in `<? extends Identity>` and `<? extends T>`. Can you control those signatures and use a non-wildcard form?

Comment: @E-Riz - It's not code I originally wrote but I can change signatures. How is it supposed to be defined?

Comment: Apparently you have both `com.mypackage.ReadApiResponse` and `com.mypackage.model.ReadApiResponse` (notice the ‘model’ subpackage in the second name).  They are not the same class, so you will have to pick one and use it in both places.

Comment: @VGR might be right, if that's not just a typo in your code/message. Do you have 2 different classes named `ReadApiResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the wildcard generic type constraints like follows, it should be easier to work with:

```java
public interface MyApi<T extends Identity> {
    List<ReadApiResponse<T>> read(ReadApiRequest request);
}

public class MyClass<T extends Identity> {

    private List<T> sortResults(List<ReadApiResponse<T>> response) {
         // Do something here
      }

}
```

Note that, depending on the usage and the type `Identity`, this might eliminate some flexibility that you get by using wildcard type constraints. Without more context, it's impossible to say for sure if that will matter.